# Delete specific streams from a media file without creating a copy of the media file

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, video-editing

## The context

I have a file with four streams: 1 video stream, 3 audio streams (see proof below).

```
$ ffprobe -v quiet -of flat -show_entries stream=codec_type,index:stream_tags=title 'my_input_file.mkv'
streams.stream.0.index=0
streams.stream.0.codec_type="video"
streams.stream.1.index=1
streams.stream.1.codec_type="audio"
streams.stream.1.tags.title="English"
streams.stream.2.index=2
streams.stream.2.codec_type="audio"
streams.stream.2.tags.title="Português (BR)"
streams.stream.3.index=3
streams.stream.3.codec_type="audio"
streams.stream.3.tags.title="Português (PT)"
```

I want to delete the 2 portuguese audio stream from the `my_input_file.mkv`, so I've written the following command. This command will output a file with name `my_output_file.mkv` containing the video stream and the English audio stream (see proof below)

```
$ ffmpeg -v quiet -i 'my_input_file.mkv' -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 'my_output_file.mkv'
$ ffprobe -v quiet -of flat -show_entries stream=codec_type,index:stream_tags=title 'my_output_file.mkv'
streams.stream.0.index=0
streams.stream.0.codec_type="video"
streams.stream.1.index=1
streams.stream.1.codec_type="audio"
streams.stream.1.tags.title="English"
```

## The problem

Now I have two files, so I need to delete the other one. However, I'm worried about the computational cost of this workaround: Create a copy of the source and then delete the source. I think that this would be faster if only I could strip specific streams from the source without creating a copy.

I've tried executing the following command (see code block below). However, it seems that `ffmpeg` cannot edit files in-place.

```
$ ffmpeg -v warning -i 'my_input_file.mkv' -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 'my_input_file.mkv'
File 'my_input_file.mkv' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Output my_input_file.mkv same as Input #0 - exiting
FFmpeg cannot edit existing files in-place.
```

## The question

Is there any tool/way that would result in the source file not containing those two audio streams without creating a copy of the source file?

I've seen that people recommend the tools from [`mkvtoolnix`](https://mkvtoolnix.download/). However, I've never used those commannds, so I wonder if any of those commands could accomplish that.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. As the message says, you cannot overwrite an existing file in-place, so when you want to modify it, you always have to first copy it somewhere else, then rename the file. Stream-copying is very cheap, computationally, so all you need is the disk space.

PS: I don't know of any program that would allow in-place edits without resorting to temporary files. Unless you can load the entire (new) file into memory and write it from there. Of course, in-place editing can be done with text files very easily. However it would be rather unsafe and not very practical, in particular for large media files.